# Looping through two arrays -> mark checkbox check

Tags: php, arrays

Iam stuck when comparing two arrays.

In first array, I have IDs of rows, where I need to mark checkbox ckecked. In second array, there is a full dataset of items from table.

I had no luck to make it work properly yet - here is my last attempt which obviously don't work properly as it does everything 6 times (as first array contains 6 elements)

First array:
**array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "24"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "25"
  [2]=>
  string(2) "28"
  [3]=>
  string(1) "8"
  [4]=>
  string(1) "9"
  [5]=>
  string(2) "10"
}**

**$products** - array of 6 elements

**$data** - array of dataset pulled from mysql

```
foreach($datas as $data) { 
if(!empty($products)) {
    foreach($products as $product) { 
        if($product == $data->id) { ?>
            <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="selectedProduct[]" value="<?=$data->id;?>" class="big-checkbox" checked="checked">
            <td><?=$data->evidenceId;?></td>
            <td><?=$data->modelName;?></td>
            <td><?=$data->size;?></td>
            <td><?=$data->price;?></td>
            <td><?=$data->brand;?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php } 
        if($product !== $data->id) { ?>
            <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="selectedProduct[]" value="<?=$data->id;?>" class="big-checkbox">
            <td><?=$data->evidenceId;?></td>
            <td><?=$data->modelName;?></td>
            <td><?=$data->size;?></td>
            <td><?=$data->price;?></td>
            <td><?=$data->brand;?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php }
    }
}
```

What I need is to render each row from $data and mark box checked where **$data->id == $product**

Any advices?
Thank you!
Martin

**EDIT:**

Also tried approach like this, but it only screwed the html table:

```
foreach($datas as $data) { 
                                    foreach($selectedProducts as $product) {
                                        if($product == $data->id) { ?>
                                            <tr>
                                            <td><input type="checkbox" name="selectedProduct[]" value="<?=$data->id;?>" class="big-checkbox" checked="checked"> 
                                        <?php }
                                        if($product !== $data->id) { ?>
                                            <tr>
                                            <td><input type="checkbox" name="selectedProduct[]" value="<?=$data->id;?>" class="big-checkbox">
                                        <?php }
                                    }
                                ?>

                                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="selectedProduct[]" value="<?=$data->id;?>" class="big-checkbox">
                                        <td><?=$data->evidenceId;?></td>
                                        <td><?=$data->modelName;?></td>
                                        <td><?=$data->size;?></td>
                                        <td><?=$data->price;?></td>
                                        <td><?=$data->brand;?></td>
                                    </tr>
                                <?php } ?>
```

Comment: First array is what? $datas?

Comment: @some-non-descript-user: nope, first array is **$product**. **$datas** is dataset pulled from mysql.

Comment: Can you show the result of `$datas`?

Comment: @aldrin27 
`array(29) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#25 (7) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "24"
    ["evidenceId"]=>
    string(2) "29"
    ["modelName"]=>
    string(19) "Rossignol červené"
    ["size"]=>
    string(2) "27"
    ["price"]=>
    string(3) "650"
    ["type"]=>
    string(5) "Lyže"
    ["brand"]=>
    string(2) "K2"
  }`

Comment: And the result of `$selectedProducts`?

Comment: @aldrin27: It is the same as **$products** - I renamed it during the time i troubleshoot that issue.. it is the same content -> array of IDs to be marked check

Comment: Yes but can you show the result of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $products contains the product ids you can check if a products has to be selected with in_array(). No need for a second loop.

```
if(!empty($products)) {
    foreach($datas as $data) { 
    ?>
        <tr>
    <?php 
        if(in_array($data->id, $products) { 
    ?>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="selectedProduct[]" value="<?=$data->id;?>" class="big-checkbox" checked="checked"></td>
    <?php
        }else{
    ?>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="selectedProduct[]" value="<?=$data->id;?>" class="big-checkbox"></td>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
       <td><?=$data->evidenceId;?></td>
       <td><?=$data->modelName;?></td>
       <td><?=$data->size;?></td>
       <td><?=$data->price;?></td>
       <td><?=$data->brand;?></td>
       </tr>

    }
}
```

...and your code lacks a closing td tag.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Thank you, buddy.

Answer (score 0):

try this code
assuming your products array contains (model name, size...)
and data array contain product ids of selected products

```
<?php
//collect seelcted IDs
$selectedIds = array();
foreach($datas as $data){
    $selectedIds[]=$data->id;
}
//now loop through products, and check if current product_id exists (in_array()) in selectedIds echo checked else nothing
foreach($products as $product) { 
?>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="product_n" value="<?=$product->id;?>" class="big-checkbox" <?php echo (in_array($product->id,$selectedIds?"checked='checked'":"")) ?> >
        <td><?=$product->evidenceId;?></td>
        <td><?=$product->modelName;?></td>
        <td><?=$product->size;?></td>
        <td><?=$product->price;?></td>
        <td><?=$product->brand;?></td>
    </tr>
<?php
    }
?>
```